# how can I merge the rows as column next to the matrix in R?

Tags: r

I want to merge the rows of the data.frame next to the column? Look at the `d1` and `d2` please, `d1` is my data.frame and output is `d2` ?

```
d1<-data.frame(ID=c(1:3),
               Loc1=c(100,121,146))


d2<-data.frame(ID=c(1,1,2), Loc1x=c(100,100,121), 
               ID=c(2,3,4), Loc1y=c(121,146,146))
```

or in the another dataset,

```
d3<-data.frame(Samp=c("1167.p1","1187.p1" ), Chr=c("chr1", "chr2"), Loc=c(7,6) )
```

Comment: Where is the matrix

Comment: sorry dataframe, d1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope the code below can help a bit

```
do.call(
  rbind,
  c(
    make.row.names = FALSE,
    Map(
      function(z) do.call(cbind, split(z, 1:nrow(z))),
      combn(1:nrow(d1), 2, FUN = function(k) d1[k, ], simplify = FALSE)
    )
  )
)
```

which gives

```
  1.ID 1.Loc1 2.ID 2.Loc1
1    1    100    2    121
2    1    100    3    146
3    2    121    3    146
```

---

With `d3`, we try

```
do.call(
  rbind,
  c(
    make.row.names = FALSE,
    Map(
      function(z) do.call(cbind, split(z, 1:nrow(z))),
      combn(1:nrow(d3), 2, FUN = function(k) d3[k, ], simplify = FALSE)
    )
  )
)
```

and will get

```
   1.Samp 1.Chr 1.Loc  2.Samp 2.Chr 2.Loc
1 1167.p1  chr1     7 1187.p1  chr2     6
```

Comment: thanks but it is not working for characteristic value:S

Comment: @henryTi What do you mean by `characterstic value`?

Comment: character sorry

Comment: sorry, this is working for this example, but it didn't work for my data

Comment: @henryTi I have no clue if you don't provide a small example about your data

Comment: In my example Loc is numeric and the output must be numeric too.